# Simple Array.prototype is giving a TypeError

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, typeerror

I have this (very simple) code:

```
Array.prototype.test = function(x) { alert(x) }
[0].test('Hello, World!')
```

However, when I execute it, I get this:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'test' of undefined
```

What is wrong?

Comment: (this is a *very* weird error that I spent a while debugging, so I decided to post it here for future reference to help other programmers later)

Comment: If you prefer to omit semicolons, then it can be helpful to simply never start a line with `[` or `(`. I usually just do something like `;[0].test(...)`.

Comment: don't forget to always add semis after a method assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this this odd error, and I finally figured out that the solution is to add semicolons:

```
Array.prototype.test = function(x) { alert(x) };
[0].test('Hello, World!');
```

---

Otherwise, it would be parsed like this:

```
Array.prototype.test = function(x) { alert(x) }[0].test('Hello, World!')
```

`function(x) { alert(x) }[0]` is undefined because function objects don't have a property called `0`, so it becomes

```
Array.prototype.test = undefined.test('Hello, World!')
```

Then, it tries to call `test` on `undefined`, which it of course can't do, so it gives an error.

Comment: Useful reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi